# What is the "fine art term" for office printer as medium?

Tags: terminology, printing

I'm submitting artwork that uses prints from an office printer, and I want to describe that in the list of mediums used

Pencil is referred to as "graphite" so, is there a term for using an office printer for fine art?

Comment: Inkjet or Laser?

Answer (score 5):

Chris H's comment is the answer in a nutshell: **the description should include the medium, and depends on the *type* of printing**. If it's an inkjet print, you can state that; if it's a laser print, the artwork's description could say so. You can also just say 'digital print', combining all digital printing possibilities.

**Often the type of paper** - if exceptional or otherwise deemed important for the artwork - **is also included** in the description (e.g. 'giclée print on 210 gr Hahnemuhle Albrecht Durer paper').

**Ultimately, though, you describe the print in as much detail as you think is right towards your audience or clients**. In some instances you could even be emphatically vague about it if you think it accentuates (the concept of) a particular artwork.
The 'office' in 'office printer' doesn't matter for the technology used, as far as it concerns the quality of the prints, but if you think that fact is important for understanding your piece, it's completely fine to include that.

---

You can also have a look [here](https://www.artsy.net/collection/prints) and [here](http://www.artnet.com/artists/) to see what terminology is used (which also includes vague terms like 'pigment' and 'photo print').

Answer (score 3):

The *art form* is called **photocopy art**, **copier art**, **xerox art** or sometimes just **xerography** with copier art being the most common. It was an experimental art form that originated with artists putting objects on the copy bed and using the copy process to generate the work of art, often manipulating and then recopying multiple times to get the final piece.

That would be different from just using a printer to reproduce an existing work of art. This is specifically art works that use the copier/printer as a tool to give the work its unique qualities.

Comment: To me copier art would appear to be at best a subset of what the OP is after.  Their workflow would appear to involve digitally-generated or -modified material, which is then printed taking account of the characteristics of the printer.  There's no mention of a copier.

Comment: Yeah, thought about that but it wasn't clear in OP question. A slightly archaic term but IF the art was about using the office printer as part of the process this seemed closest name for it. Otherwise Joachim is right, just name the type of print in the materials listed.