# What is the name of my drawing style? Black and white?

Tags: drawing, terminology, style-identification

I'm looking for a term for my art drawings. I'm going to post a gig on Fiverr and I don't know what to call it (black and white art/drawing?). There has to be a name for it. I have been drawing using black ink on white paper ever since I was a kid, and my drawings are really cool. Now I'm using Photoshop to edit my hand drawings and they look even better. I'm starting to think of a job using my talent, but if I don't know a way to describe my art people won't find me.

I'm looking for a way to describe my artwork and artworks that are similar.

[image]

addition:
The technique I'm using is to draw a shape, then add lines, points, and designs in and around it. Then I do the same for another shape near it, then merge the two shapes together, making sure that I hide what is the starting shape by drawing in it.

Comment: Maybe a monochrome artist? Or grisaille artist if you paint. Im not really sure what other words there would be.

Comment: It's total not grisaille, but monochrome I don't know? When i search Google I saw 2% similar drawings. I just don't know.

Comment: When I first saw it, it reminded me of henna tattoos.

Comment: yes agarza it's 80% similar to  henna tattoos, do you know why?
it's because the drawing don't have a really shap to use or a rules, it used any shap and start add line and point and design In and around it, then make the same for other shap near it, then mirge the two shaps together.

Comment: This is a technique, not a style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Black and white is the colour scheme of your drawing - it is never a style.

The medium is ink on paper, if digitally cleaned up and printed it can be described as a [print](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/8176/what-is-the-fine-art-term-for-office-printer-as-medium) (and you might want to consider working in (limited) editions).

The technique, depending on your drawing method, seems to be free drawing, akin to [free writing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_writing) (and in that case an intentional form of doodling), or '*automatic* drawing', the drawing counterpart to [automatic writing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_writing).

Since these methods usually produce an idiomatic decorative pattern (as user *agarza* mentions in the comments, it is similar to henna drawings, or [mehndi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mehndi)), they can be used to describe a style as well, simply because it will tell people what to expect. But a better way to go about it is to see what makes *your* artwork *yours*, what is unique about it, and either combine that with 'doodling', 'doodles', or 'free/automatic drawing', depending on what kind of audience you want to appeal to.
For instance, your drawing also reminds me of a more abstract and asymmetrical and less geographical form of the luscious [*horror vacui*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horror_vacui) ornaments and illuminations in manuscripts:

[image]

<sup>Gothic Ornament with Putti and Acanthus Leaves, 19th century.

[Source](https://www.metmuseum.org/art/collection/search/382725).

Click for larger version.</sup>

Hence, '*ornamental free drawing*' *could* be a way to describe your artwork.
Ultimately, you know best what you want to achieve and what kind of clients you want to attract, so play around with the suggestions given here in the comments and answers until you find something you think is appropriate for your artwork.

Comment: I totally agree with you. It's more like ornamental free drawing and an intentional form of doodling or 'automatic drawing' and similar to henna tattoos. Reading these answers and comments gave me more ideas. And your answer is even better. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

Although your work is more abstract, it immediately reminded me of the work of British illustrator [Ian Miller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ian_Miller_(illustrator)).  [His term](https://www.ian-miller.org/) for the style of his (especially) black-and-white work was "Tight Pen Style," although I don't think that terminology was every picked up more widely.

You may seen some similarity to your own work in this fantastical floating tree

[image: Miller Illustration]

Or in this illustration of [Gormenghast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gormenghast_(series)).

[image: Illustration of Gormenghast]

Miller tends to apply this technical style to produce works with a fairly grotesque or gothic character, but I don't know to what extent that applies to your work.

Comment: The fantastical floating tree is a very similar drawing, please see my addition in the question. You're right: my work is more abstract. I'll accept your answer if there is not really name for my art but a similar art.